# Silverlight: reposition child window to center

Tags: c#, silverlight

The content inside the child window changes, which causes my child window to lose it's center alignment.... After the content has changed is there anyway to reposition the child window to center... I tried the following and it did not work:

```
this.horizontalalignment = horizontalalignment.center;
this.verticalalignment = verticalalignment.center;
```

Thanks

Comment: You are changing the size of the ChildWindow via the Height and Width properties?

Answer (score 9):

The presence of a RenderTransform on the ChildWindow template seems to be to blame.   The TransformGroup is part of the default template to allow you to move around the window.

Here is a hack to reset the transform after you change the layout:

```
        //after you do some change to the childwindow layout
        sp.Children.Add(new Button() { Content = "a" });

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            //reset the transform to zero
            (this.GetTemplateChild("ContentRoot") as Grid).RenderTransform = new TransformGroup()
            {
                Children = { new ScaleTransform(), new SkewTransform(), new RotateTransform(), new TranslateTransform() }
            };
        });
```

or more automatically:

```
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        var contentRoot = this.GetTemplateChild("ContentRoot") as FrameworkElement;
        contentRoot.LayoutUpdated += contentRoot_LayoutUpdated;
    }

    void contentRoot_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var contentRoot = this.GetTemplateChild("ContentRoot") as FrameworkElement;
        var tg = contentRoot.RenderTransform as TransformGroup;
        var tts = tg.Children.OfType<TranslateTransform>();
        foreach (var t in tts)
        {
            t.X = 0; t.Y = 0;
        }
    }
```

LayoutUpdated gets called often, so you may want to check if contentRoot.ActualWidth and ActualHeight changed to see if you really need to wipe out the transform.

Comment: This solved my problem and 'it just works'.  I would suggest people add a bit of null ref checking but other than that it just works.

Answer (score 0):

Code

```
public partial class DialogOptions : ChildWindow
{
    public DialogOptions()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Loaded += (sender, args) =>
        {
            VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
            this.SetWindowPosition(new Point(0, 200));
        };
    }
}
```

And extention:

```
    public static void SetWindowPosition(this ChildWindow childWindow, Point point)
    {
        var root = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(childWindow, 0) as FrameworkElement;

        if (root == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var contentRoot = root.FindName("ContentRoot") as FrameworkElement;

        if (contentRoot == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var group = contentRoot.RenderTransform as TransformGroup;

        if (group == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        TranslateTransform translateTransform = null;

        foreach (var transform in group.Children.OfType<TranslateTransform>())
        {
            translateTransform = transform;
        }

        if (translateTransform == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        translateTransform.X = point.X;
        translateTransform.Y = point.Y;        
    }
```